# Migrated question and email notification

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, migration, notifications

It seems that a migrated question does not appear in the email notifications of its tags.

*Question*: Should it appear?

By *migrated question* I mean a question migrated on mathoverflow, and by *e-mail notifications* I mean notifications created using [filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters) (corresponding to the option subscribe/unsubscribe of the tag).